# Package instance dependencies

Tags: haskell

I'm developing two packages, one has a class, the other a data type. This packages can be used independently, but when used together, it makes sense for the data type to be an instance of the class.

Is there a way to define this relationship without making one of the packages depend on another?

Here's a simple example, lets say I've got a `Car` package and a `Print` package. There's a way to "print" cars, but if I've got no interest into printing, I should be able to use the `Car` package by itself. Likewise, if I've got no interest in `Car`s, I should be able to use the print package by itself.

Is the only solution to create a third package, `PrintCars`, that depends on the previous two?

(The reason why I'm asking this is that I'm defining a new class which I want to include lots of sensible instances for existing types (as well as one of my own), but I don't want to depend on a whole bunch of large packages nor make a separate package for each combination).

Comment: This is a pretty frequent unsolved issue with Haskell package management, and I'm sure everyone would love a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

An instance must depend on the `Car` type and the `Printable` class, unless it is possible to derive `Printable` from other classes of which `Car` is an instance. (A very simple but useless example would be if `Printable` were defined as `class Show a => Printable a`, and there is an instance `Show Car`.)

You could define an instance `Print Car` in a third package, but this would be an [orphan instance](https://wiki.haskell.org/Orphan_instance).

A workaround for orphanness, as described in the page I linked, is to create a `newtype`, for example:

```
newtype PrintableCar = PrintableCar Car

instance Print PrintableCar where
    print (PrintableCar car) = ...
```

Now, to print a car you must wrap it in the `PrintableCar` constructor.